# IMPORTXML issue: How to pull data from a Yahoo Fantasy Team Page?

Tags: xml, xpath, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am starting a fantasy football league with some friends, and we will be operating it in the offseason (dynasty/keeper). I am building a Google Spreadsheet to help synchronize the activity on the Yahoo page with a Google Spreadsheet.

Mainly I have been using `IMPORTHTML` to bring tables of information from my league into the Google Spreadsheet, and then processing the data there. I recently discovered the `IMPORTXML` function and I have been trying to figure out how I can use it to grab data from various pages of our league.

Here is an example of one of our team pages: http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/7977/2

I watched a few videos and read a few blogs that basically said you put the copy of **XPATH** information into the `IMPORTXML`, but that keeps giving me an error.

For example, I tried to grab the position/name/stats for Matt Stafford.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/7977/2", //* @id="yui_3_10_3_1_1407351196962_1052"])
```

I have tried all kinds of tweaks suggested on SO and other sites, including changing " to ', and adding `[@` after div, but nothing seems to be working.

Any helpful hints? I have never tried to do any kind of coding before, but it has been thrilling to build my spreadsheet in the last few weeks and learn. I  would love it if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Dan

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you an error because you need to be authenticated in order to access this URL: http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/7977/2

You can confirm it if you will open an incognito mode (in chrome) or private mode in FF and go to this url - Yahoo will ask you to authenticate yourself.

There is an option to run OAuth in Apps Script. 
Checkout their API at: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/o-auth-config

You will need to first authenticate and later make the IMPORTXML call.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into figuring out authentication. This could be very useful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the league 'Publicly Viewable' in the settings. Then, use the following formulas to pull the data needed:

```
=importhtml("http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/7977/players?status=ALL&pos=O&cut_type=9&stat1=S_S_2014&myteam=0&sort=PR&sdir=1&count=0","table",0)
```

Use that formula to pull each "page" of ranks, so the next set of data `count=25`, `50`, etc. This takes a few min to setup. I can share a page if you want to see it. (I put your League ID above, but it didn't work, so I'm guessing you are not publicly viewable.) Then I use the below formulas to parse out the data. (The formulas are in Column N)

```
Column H - `=iferror(split(O1,char(10)))`
Column F - `=iferror(split(E1," ",false))`
Column D - `=iferror(split(I1,"- ",false))`
Column A - `=iferror(LEFT(TRIM(D1),FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(D1," ","~",LEN(TRIM(D1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(D1)," ",""))))-1))`
```

(You may be able to eliminate the Column F formula.) These formula's strip off all the data except the player name. Then you can use various cell formulas to lookup the stats/position/owner/etc from each player.